# How to tell spring about a singleton class that is used in a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring bean like:

```
public class MongoDaoImpl implements MongoDao {
   private static final Mongo mongo = new Mongo(MySettings.INSTANCE.getMongoHost());

}
```

In my servlet.xml I have:

```
   <bean id="mongoDao" class="com.abc.dao.MongoDaoImpl">

   </bean>
```

Now I get an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class MongoDaoImpl
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
```

MySettings looks like:

```
public enum MySettings {
    INSTANCE; 

    private String mongoHost;

    private MySettings() {
       mongoHost = "127.0.0.1";
    }

    public String getMongoHost() {
       return mongoHost;
    }
}
```

So it seems when spring tries to setup MongoDaoImpl, it crashes because of MySettings.
If I remove MySettings in the mongoDaoImpl and just hard code "127.0.0.1" things work fine.

Do I have to wire up MySettings in a bean and then somehow tell MongoDaoImpl about it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly this is failing (shouldn't be), but your `Mongo` instance should also be a bean. Declare it in your xml, and use property placeholders so that you can configure it with `.properties` files. Something like:

```
<bean id="mongo" class="...Mongo">
    <constructor-arg value="${mongo.host}" />
</bean>
```

Btw, why don't you use `MongoTemplate` from [spring-data-mongodb](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb)?

Answer (score 0):

Try if any of following helps

1. Check if full class/package name in XML is correct. If this one works then you should use initialization method suggested by Bozho (above answer#1)
2. Remove static declaration from your class and try starting the spring container again
3. Change logging level to to debug to get more information